# Rails has_many association with multiple keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, models

I am trying to bend rails around a legacy database. Each of the tables have a 'datasource' column that is a 3 char code of where the data came from. So in order to uniquely identify and relate to the other tables you have to have two pieces of information (e.g. account number and datasource).

The has_many relationship I have below works fine, unless I try to include in on query.

```
# Model Association
has_many :transactions,
         :primary_key => :account,
         :foreign_key => :acnt,
         :order => :ddate,
         :conditions => ['datasource = ?', '#{self.datasource}']

# Controller code FAIL when I loop through results in view and call 'account.transactions'
@accounts = Account.includes(:transactions).where(:lname => 'Smith')

# However, this controller code works when I loop through the results in the view and call 'account.transactions'
@accounts = Account.where(:lname => 'Smith')

# View
<% @accounts.each do |a| %>
  <% a.transactions.each do |t| %>
    <%= t.description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `datasource' for #<Class:0x1025f25c8>):
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

Broke down and customized the finder_sql. Looks like it works, so far...

```
  has_many :transactions,
           :primary_key => :account,
           :foreign_key => :acnt,
           :finder_sql =>
               'SELECT t.* ' +
               'FROM accounts a, transactions t ' +
               'WHERE a.acnt = t.account AND a.datasource = t.datasource ' +
               'ORDER BY t.ddate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your condition inside of quotes

```
has_many :transactions,
         :primary_key => :account,
         :foreign_key => :acnt,
         :order => :ddate,
         :conditions => ['datasource = "#{self.datasource}"']
```

Comment: self.datasource will raise an error since datasource is not a class attribute. self refers to Account class here not the instance.

Comment: you're wrong, because `self` is parent's (transaction.account) object (actually instance).

Comment: I was getting the same error. Only when using Account.includes(), though.

Comment: @Deepak N, sorry, when we use `Model.includes(assoc)`, `self` will return `Model` object, and when we use `Model.last.assoc` `self will return `Model` instance. That's the topic problem actually

Answer (score 0):

Your condition statement is wrong. Try this.

> :conditions =>
>   ['transactions.datasource =
>   accounts.datasource']

Comment: when using has_many "accounts" table is not in the FROM statement, therefore this condition is invalid.