# Rails has_many :through with :primary_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship with rails has_many through: but instead of using the models primary key (id) I need to create the relationship using a different column.
Here are my models (Btw, I am using Rails 4):

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :NDB_No, uniqueness: true
  validates :NDB_No, :FdGrp_Cd, :Long_Desc, :Shrt_Desc, presence: true

  has_many :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'NDB_No', foreign_key: 'NDB_No'
  has_many :langual_factor_descriptions, through: :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'NDB_No', foreign_key: 'NDB_No'
end

class LangualFactorAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :NDB_No, :Factor_Code, presence: true

  belongs_to :food, foreign_key: 'NDB_No'
  belongs_to :langual_factor_description, foreign_key: 'Factor_Code'
end

class LangualFactorDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :Factor_Code, uniqueness: true
  validates :Factor_Code, :Description, presence: true

  has_many :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'Factor_Code', foreign_key: 'Factor_Code'
  has_many :foods, through: :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'Factor_Code', foreign_key: 'Factor_Code'

end
```

The has_many association with LangualFactorAssociation works correctly for both Food and LangualFactorDescription. But the has_many through: association between Food and LangualFactorDescription does not work. Here is the error I get when I try to access Food.LangualFactorDescriptions:

```
Food::should create the proper relations to the LangualFactorDescription
            model#test_0002_must create the proper associations:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...sociations" ON "langual_factor_descriptions"."id" = "langual...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "langual_factor_descriptions".* FROM "langual_factor_descriptions" INNER JOIN "langual_factor_associations" ON "langual_factor_descriptions"."id" = "langual_factor_associations"."Factor_Code" WHERE "langual_factor_associations"."NDB_No" = $1  ORDER BY "langual_factor_descriptions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    test/models/food_test.rb:172:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I think the problem is this part of the query **ON "langual_factor_descriptions"."id" = "langual_factor_associations"."Factor_Code"**. I thought that setting primary_key and/or foreign_key options would fix this but it didn't. In fact if I remove those from the model and just leave it like

```
has_many :langual_factor_descriptions, through: :langual_factor_associations
```

rails produces the exact same query, so it seems to me that setting those options does nothing. Am I missing something here? Any idea on how I can tell rails to do not look for the langual_factor_descriptions.id but instead langual_factor_descriptions.Factor_Code?

Here are some of the most relevant resources that I have read about this topic:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

[has_many :through with :primary_key on join table not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714857/has-many-through-with-primary-key-on-join-table-not-working) (this is pretty much the problem I have but I am not sure that's the proper solution)

[Rails has_many association with multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290894/rails-has-many-association-with-multiple-keys)

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139765

[Has Many Through Alternative Primary and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285649/has-many-through-alternative-primary-and-foreign-keys)

Comment: i'm not sure,you can try self.primary_key = 'Factor_Code' in model LangualFactorDescription

Comment: Alright!, that worked. But I have a question: is it OK to define that field as primary in the model even though the primary key in the DB remains the id?.

Comment: i think that is ok, i think `primary_key` tell ActiveRecord which field will be used to join another table.

Comment: I see, and how about if I need to have another has_many through: relationship with another model using a different field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I fixed the problem. Here is the code:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :NDB_No, uniqueness: true
  validates :NDB_No, :FdGrp_Cd, :Long_Desc, :Shrt_Desc, presence: true

  has_many :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'NDB_No', foreign_key: 'NDB_No'
  has_many :langual_factors, through: :langual_factor_associations    
end

class LangualFactorAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :NDB_No, :Factor_Code, presence: true

  belongs_to :food, primary_key: 'NDB_No', foreign_key: 'NDB_No'
  belongs_to :langual_factor, primary_key: 'Factor_Code', foreign_key: 'Factor_Code'
end

class LangualFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :Factor_Code, uniqueness: true
  validates :Factor_Code, :Description, presence: true

  has_many :langual_factor_associations, primary_key: 'Factor_Code', foreign_key: 'Factor_Code'
  has_many :foods, through: :langual_factor_associations    
end
```

Notice that I didn't use foreign_key nor primary_key options in the has_many through: associations, and that there is no need for `self.primary_key`.

Also, here are some other useful links that helped me:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=36186

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html

Even though the solution to the problem came by coincidence, I believe those links provide relevant information.

Comment: This is when it comes to naming and best practice, one of the worst examples I've ever seen. I at least needed 3 minutes to fully understand what numbers you're using and what all refers to what. Please think about updating your example with correct naming and maybe a schema table-example.